# RecyclerView GridLayoutManager item decoration takes measured space?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am creating a vertical RecyclerView with three columns (to simplify illustration I have made the RecyclerView contain only 6 items). What I need is the items on the sides get bigger margin so I use an ItemDecoration to achieve this:

```
class SpaceDecoration : RecyclerView.ItemDecoration() {

    override fun getItemOffsets(outRect: Rect, view: View, parent: RecyclerView, state: RecyclerView.State) {
        val position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view)
        outRect.left = when(position) {
            0, 3 -> 160 // Left most two items
            else -> 10 // others
        }
        outRect.right = when(position) {
            2, 5 -> 160 // Right most two items
            else ->0 // others
        }
        outRect.top = 10
        outRect.bottom = 0
    }
}
```

What I want is the item body to have the same width. However they are not. It looks like the GridLayoutManager measures the ItemDecoration size when equally dividing the space. How can I make the items appear equal width? I certainly do not want GridLayoutManager to measure the ItemDecoration.
[image]

Here are the remaining code:

MainActivity.kt:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.grid)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this,3,  RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false)
        recyclerView.adapter = GridAdapter()
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(SpaceDecoration())
    }
}
```

GridAdapter.kt:

```
class GridAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder =
        VH(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.grid_item, parent, false))
    override fun getItemCount() = 6
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) = Unit
    class VH(item: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(item)
}
```

grid_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="48sp"
    android:text="AAA"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"/>
```

Comment: same problem. any news?

Answer (score -1):

You can just add `paddingLeft` and `paddingRight` to `recyclerView` (without any `ItemDecoration`s). There will be paddings and size of elements will be equal.